# What is the meaning of 房屋 in 比其他房屋的规模大?

Tags: meaning

> 大门一般开在东南角或西北角，院中的北房是正房，比其他房屋的规模大，一般包括长辈的卧室和具备日常起居、接待客人等功能的客厅。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 14.

What is the meaning of 房屋 here: 比其他房屋的规模大?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're after here; [房屋](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=房屋) = "house / building" can be found in dictionaries.

Comment: I know, but it looks like, here it means something different, like room. That is why I am asking.

Comment: You may be interested to know that 添房 does not mean "Extra / Additional Room(s)", but the gifts from relatives and friends of the bride's family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"院中的北房是正房" -

The ancient Chinese house of the rich usually consisted of three or four housing units, that form an upside-down "U" or "口", with a courtyard in the center and the main entrance at the south end. The surrounding housing units were then named according to their azimuth (方位) in the setting - "東廂房", "西廂房", and "上房/正房".

After the end of imperial China, people started to address those grand houses as "大院 (big court)". So the sentence - "(大)院中的北房是正房" means the north sitting housing unit (北房) is the "main housing unit (正房), and, as usual, it is larger than the other housing units (比**其他房屋**的规模大). In here, "其他房屋" means 東廂房(east housing unit) and 西廂房(west housing unit) collectively.